# Render shader on specific triangle Direct X 9

Tags: c++, directx, shader

I'm trying to get a pixel shader to run just on my triangle I'm trying to draw with drawprimitive in d3d9 but I am having trouble doing it.

This is how I'm rendering the triangle, I only call initvertexBuffer once.

```
void DxFramework::initvertexBuffer() {
    VOID* pVertices;

    MYVERTEX Vertices[] =
    {
        { 250.0f, 100.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, WHITE(255), }, // white with alpha of 255, this works fine.
        { 400.0f, 350.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, WHITE(255), },
        { 100.0f, 350.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, WHITE(255), },
    };


    if (FAILED(pDevice->CreateVertexBuffer(3 * sizeof(MYVERTEX),
        0, (D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE),
        D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &g_pVertexBuffer, NULL)))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (FAILED(g_pVertexBuffer->Lock(0, sizeof(Vertices), &pVertices, 0)))
    {
        return;
    }

    memcpy(pVertices, Vertices, sizeof(Vertices));

    g_pVertexBuffer->Unlock();
}

void DxFramework::rendertriangle() {

    pDevice->SetStreamSource(0, g_pVertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(MYVERTEX));
    pDevice->SetFVF((D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE));
    pDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 1);



}
```

And I'm calling rendertriangle like so :

```
  pEffect->SetTexture("origframeTex2D", backBufferTexture);
    pEffect->SetTexture("frameTex2D", buffer2Tex);
    pEffect->Begin(&passes, 0);
    pEffect->BeginPass(3);
    rendertriangle();
    pEffect->EndPass();
    pEffect->End();
```

Yet the triangle is just black on my screen, although I know my shader works fine and have tested it on the whole backbuffer before.

Also if anyone can provide resources on d3d9 shader drawing 2d I would appreciate it as I have found little to no resources.

Comment: Legacy DIrect3D 9 is quite old, so I'm unsure why you are using it in the first place. The 'mainstream' version of Direct3D today that works on basically all Windows systems and all video hardware is Direct3D 11, which is probably a much better starting point. For 2D drawing with Direct3D 11, take a look at ``SpriteBatch`` in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I am hooking into preexisting direct x devices so I have no choice on what version to use.

Comment: Old post but there are some issues in your code: you are mixing fixed function pipeline and shader